# caused by:duplicate source for resource: com.my.test.exception.TestException +SonarQube 4.0 +LINUX

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, sonarqube

Issue is with SonarQube 4.0 in LINUX -

One more problem with SonarQube 4.0 in linux -Getting error -caused by :duplicate source for resource
 This is due to same java file with full qualified name same.How to resolve this conflict with Java files having same name with same package but in different modules.Please note like this there are couples of java files so option of excluding individual java files is not that I want to go with.

But this is working in SonarQube 4.4 in Windows.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working on any platform with SonarQube 4.2 or later, as we redesigned the way that resources (files, folders) are referenced in SQ (full path starting at the root directory instead of path starting at the source directories).
So if you upgrade your SQ instance on Linux to 4.4 for instance, this will solve your problem.

*Just a note*: having twice the same Java class in different folders is definitely a very bad idea IMO. This tends to indicate that you have design issues in your code.